# Drop-down menu disappears when moving mouse away from parent

Tags: html, css

**The Code:**

```css
.dropDown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropDown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropDown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropDown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.dropDown:hover + .dropDown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navRight">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropDown"><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
    <div class="dropDown-content">
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When mouse hovers the `.dropDown` - the menu appears, but when mouse moves onto the `.dropDown-content` -  menu disappears. Probably there is a simple solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to display on `.dropDown + .dropDown-content:hover` too:

```css
.dropDown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropDown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropDown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropDown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.dropDown:hover + .dropDown-content,
.dropDown + .dropDown-content:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navRight">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropDown">
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
    </li>
    <div class="dropDown-content">
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
      <a href="#">TEST</a>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```